# ™ character not properly translated by GetStringChars()

Tags: java, c++, unicode, java-native-interface

I noticed that the trademark character `™` doesn't seems to be translated properly by JNI's `GetStringChars()` function in Java 8, which is supposed to translate Unicode characters.  I have the same problem with the `GetStringUTFChars()` method.

This is not a big issue, as there are easy workarounds (remove Unicode characters from the string before calling the JNI function).

But as I haven't found similar problems while Googling, I came here to see if anyone has an explanation about this? (Or maybe I'm missing something in my code ?)

I'm using Java 8 and g++ 4.8 under MinGW.

Here are my code snippets :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_JNI_myMethod (JNIEnv * env , jobject obj, jstring input_string)
{
    const jchar *inp_string = (*env).GetStringChars(input_string, NULL);
    const jchar *jch_inp_string = inp_string;         
    (*env).ReleaseStringChars(input_string, inp_string);       

    std::cout << jch_inp_string <<'\n';   
}
```

As an example, with this function, if I input this string:

```
Random String™
```

it outputs this:

```
Random Stringâ„¢
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: std::wcout is unknown to my compiler, i have this error when i compile with it :  error: 'wout' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: _"error: 'wout' is not a member of 'std' "_  If you really wrote `wout` instead of `wcout` then that error is to be expected.

Comment: sorry for the typographic mistake, it gives the same result as above by the way.

Comment: `jchar` is a 16-bit type, but `std::cout` expects `char` data instead. `GetStringChars()` returns a Java string's characters in UTF-16 encoding. Since `jchar` is not the same as C++'s `char` type, passing a `jchar*` to `std::cout` will not print out any chars at all, as it would invoke the `operator<<(void*)` overload, which just prints out a pointer's raw memory address. `â„¢` is what happens when `™` is first encoded to UTF-8 and then reinterpreted as ANSI. But the code you have shown is not doing that. You would have had to call `GetStringUTFChars()` instead to get UTF-8 data.

Comment: But passing the `jchar*` as-is to `std::wcout` should work fine, at least on platforms where `wchar_t` is 16-bit (ie, Windows). Also, you are calling `ReleaseStringChars()` too soon. You can't safely use `jch_inp_string` after you have released the data that it points at. You need to call `std::cout`/`std::wcout` before releasing the data, otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround after a deep dive in docs, it is because java support only UTF8 modified, that means it's good enough to print an XML doc, but not to print latin-1 encoded characters without errors.

To do so i called back java from c++ and made him convert his utf8 modified chars to an encoding matching my needs.
Thought i wonder if there are easiest way to do so, i find quite weird that JNI natively gives strings not fully matching a very common standard.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyClass_JNI_myMethod (JNIEnv * env , jobject obj, jstring input_string){

    //this calls back JNI to reformat the string form java UTF8 modified encoding to something more common
    const jclass stringClass = env->GetObjectClass(input_string);
    const jmethodID getBytes = env->GetMethodID(stringClass, "getBytes", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");
    const jstring charsetName = env->NewStringUTF("windows-1252");
    const jbyteArray stringJbytes = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(input_string, getBytes, charsetName);
    env->DeleteLocalRef(charsetName);
    const jsize length = env->GetArrayLength(stringJbytes);
    const jbyte* strBytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(stringJbytes, NULL); 


    //this make sure our string is C/C++ compliant with null character
    //but it seems to work well without too
    char* my_string = malloc(length+1);
    memcpy( my_string , strBytes, length);
    my_string [length] = '\0';

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(stringJbytes, strBytes , JNI_ABORT); 
    env->DeleteLocalRef(stringJbytes);  

    std::cout << my_string << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: This code is completely unnecessary. Not only is Windows-1252 not suitable for handling the majority of Unicode characters (you should be using `"utf-8"` instead when calling `String.getBytes()`), but this code is also leaking allocated memory, as you are not calling `free(my_string)` (you shouldn't even be using `malloc()` in C++, use `new[]` or better `std::string` instead). If you feel the need to call `String.getBytes()`, you don't need to allocate a second copy of the bytes, you can pass the original bytes directly to `std::cout`, eg: `std::cout.write((char*)strBytes, length);`